# Locked myself out of Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall, vnc

Im after some help desperately!

I currently have a server running ubuntu 14.04.  I access it using a macbook pro and chicken VNC.

All was fine until a few days ago i decided to increase security and install UFW.

When i installed it, i followed the tutorial and made sure i opened SSH.

Since then i am now unable to access the server using chicken VNC.  The server also cannot be accessed by Plex.  (I'm assuming that the firewall is doing what it is supposed to and blocking all incoming connections!)

So, im a bit stuck, i can't access the server to turn off the firewall.

I have tried plugging it into my TV and it says 'Mode not supported' (i believe this is a samsung HDTV thing) so i cant use that to get into it.  I believe this is due to it having the incorrect resolution.

I have tried using the samsung TV and getting into the GRUB menu, but as soon as it hits UBUNTU load screen, thats when my tv says it is unsupported.

Any help really appreciated!!!!!

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server?

Answer (score 0):

VNC uses port 5900, so if you didn't open that port, you have locked yourself out of access to that application.  Sign in using SSH and open the appropriate port in ufw for VNC.

Depending on your setup you may have to forward the appropriate ports in your LAN's router as well.

I'm not clear on what the TV has to do with this problem.

Comment: hi,thank you for all your help!  Do either of you have any good guides on how to access the server using SSH??  Im currently using a macbook pro to access it.  Im unsure if SSH has been enabled on the server, but i do know that i allowed it when setting up UFW

Comment: Assuming there is an ssh server running on the machine you are trying to connect to, you open a terminal window and type `ssh userid@ip-of-remote-computer`

Comment: nope unfortunately I'm getting connection refused :(

Comment: That's too bad.  Sounds like you'll have to get physical access.  There may be a way to boot it into a different resolution, if that's the problem with interfacing it to your TV, but I can't help you with that.

Comment: Note for the future, if you intent on accessing your server through ssh, install ssh server as well.